# vmware clarity datagrid what is the Number of items displayed on data grid

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, vmware-clarity

I am using VMware-Clarity for my UI, And I am using Data grid to show data, I have 8 items which is coming from the result[]. The thing is if I set [clrDgPageSize]="3" to show only 3 items to be displayed on the data grid it ends up showing all 8 items. So How can I change the number of items to be displayed on the data grid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the pagination child component in the footer like this

```
<clr-dg-pagination #pagination [clrDgPageSize]="3">
    <clr-dg-page-size [clrPageSizeOptions]="[1,3,5,10,20]">Users per page</clr-dg-page-size>
    {{pagination.firstItem + 1}} - {{pagination.lastItem + 1}}
    of {{pagination.totalItems}} users
</clr-dg-pagination>
```

Here is a working stackblitz that defaults to three rows showing: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-v1-0-so-54418713-dg-footer-pagination

Comment: Hi @hippeelee Thanks, But I am using Clarity v0.13 in that they have not mentioned about <clr-dg-page-size>, I tried using it, it throws error saying, Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'clrPageSizeOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'clr-dg-page-size'. https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.13/datagrid/pagination

Comment: Can you creat a stackblitz that recreates your issue? It helps me help you to have running code to see what’s really going on.

Comment: Created stackblitz here is the link, the same error coming up in v0.13 https://clarity-light-theme-v013.stackblitz.io

Comment: Hi @hippeelee Thanks, I used  *clrDgItems instead of *ngfor and it works.

Comment: Glad it worked. `*clrDgItems` is for when the application already has the full list of items. `*ngFor` is for when the datagrid is relying on a backend to to provide the items. I looked at your stackblitz but thats the starter version, did you fork and save the changes? I'd like to see why you were having issues w/ `*ngFor`

Comment: Hi @hippeelee here is the stackblitz with *ngFor      https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v013-braory

Comment: Hi @vinaykhegde as I mentioned `*ngFor` is used when its a server side datagrid. Here is the documentation page for server side datagrids: https://clarity.design/documentation/datagrid/server-driven

Here is a stackblitz demo that mocks a backend and enables pagination: https://stackblitz.com/edit/datagrid-with-server-side-pagination

Your solution may be different from the example depending on how the servier API handles paging, sorting filtering etc.

Comment: Hi @hippeelee Thanks for the demo with server side, Will have a look and try to implement the same.